# Updating False values in a list based on the previous iteration

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
['col1', False, False, False, False, False]
['col1', 'col2', False, False, False, False]
['col1', False, 'col3a', False, False, False]
['col1', False, 'col3b', False, False, False]
['col1', False, False, 'col4', False, False]
['col1', False, False, 'col4', False, False]
```

As I go through each row, I'm looking to see if the current item is `False` and if the item in the previous row (same pos) is not `False`, I'll replace the current item with the previous one.

So the new list of lists would be:

```
list_of_lists = [
    ['col1', False, False, False, False, False],
    ['col1', 'col2', False, False, False, False],
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3a', False, False, False],
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3b', False, False, False],
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3b', 'col4', False, False],
    ['col1', 'col2', 'col3b', 'col4', False, False],
]
```

Here is my code:

```
for row_num in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    display_list = []
    if row_num == 0:
        continue
    for col_num in range(len(list_of_lists[row_num])):
        current_row = list_of_lists[row_num][col_num]
        previous_row = list_of_lists[row_num - 1][col_num]
        if current_row == False and previous_row != False:
            display_list.append(previous_row)
        else:
            display_list.append(current_row)
    print(display_list)
```

It incorrectly outputs:

```
['col1', False, False, False, False, False]
['col1', 'col2', False, False, False, False]
['col1', 'col2', 'col3a', False, False, False]
['col1', False, 'col3b', False, False, False]
['col1', False, 'col3b', 'col4', False, False]
['col1', False, False, 'col4', False, False]
```

Why is it only revising two values? If a `False` value was replaced, in the next iteration, it seems like it does not know it changed? For example:

```
['col1', 'col2', 'col3a', False, False, False] 
['col1', False, 'col3b', False, False, False]
```

Why does 1st item in the 2nd list not know `'col2'` was updated, thus use it to replace the `False` in its position?

Comment: Hint: think carefully - exactly what does "replace the current item with the previous one" mean? Does your code actually do this? What is the relationship in your code between `display_list` and `list_of_lists`? "in the next iteration, it seems like it does not know it changed?" - well, why would it? I don't think it actually *did* change. Do you see why?

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but `current_row` and `previous_row` are confusing names, cause they refer to cells, not rows.

Comment: When you are getting the previous_row value, you are getting it from list_of_lists. This is fine for first row, but for the other rows this will not work, as they are not the updated values.

Comment: FWIW, this is really easy to do in Pandas: `df.mask(df.applymap(lambda x: x is False)).ffill().fillna(False)` This drops `False`, forward-fills columns, then puts `False` back.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you this is actually what I wanted to do, as the list of lists was a DF

Comment: @dimButTries Ah, why didn't you say that then? :) [Iteration in Pandas is an anti-pattern](/a/55557758/4518341), plus it's easier to think about this operation on columns instead of rows, which is exactly how Pandas works. Beware the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832) in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, when we calculate the previous value, I'm taking it from the display_list instead of the list_of_lists (since display_list would now have the updated values)

```
list_of_lists = [
    ['col1', False, False, False, False, False],
    ['col1', 'col2', False, False, False, False],
    ['col1', False, 'col3a', False, False, False],
    ['col1', False, 'col3b', False, False, False],
    ['col1', False, False, 'col4', False, False],
    ['col1', False, False, 'col4', False, False]
]

display_list = [[val for val in list_of_lists[0]]] # add the first row
for row_num in range(1, len(list_of_lists)): # from row 2 to end
    tmp_row = [] # for temporarily saving the updated row
    for col_num in range(len(list_of_lists[row_num])):
        current_cell = list_of_lists[row_num][col_num] # get current row from list_of_lists
        previous_cell = display_list[row_num - 1][col_num] # get previous row from display_list
        if current_cell is False and previous_cell: # pytonic way to check for falsy or truthy value
            tmp_row.append(previous_cell)
        else:
            tmp_row.append(current_cell)
    display_list.append(tmp_row) # append the tmp_row

for row in display_list:
    print(row)
```

This results in following result

```
['col1', False, False, False, False, False]
['col1', 'col2', False, False, False, False]
['col1', 'col2', 'col3a', False, False, False]
['col1', 'col2', 'col3b', False, False, False]
['col1', 'col2', 'col3b', 'col4', False, False]
['col1', 'col2', 'col3b', 'col4', False, False]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign to a `False` cell the value of the same column in the prevoius row, starting from row of index 1, since there is no previous row for a row of index 0:

```
for row in range(1, len(list_of_lists)):
    for col, value in enumerate(lst := list_of_lists[row]):
        if value is False:
            lst[col] = list_of_lists[row - 1][col]
```

Demo: [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZJBasMwEEWhS53iLwJ2wF64zaIYss0ljDBqkRKBLBlJbslZsvEmPVRPU8l2aByMoXQ2n2H0PsPoX77asz8Z3ffXzov89ftpI6xp0LZWag_ZtMb6qSMgSjpfG1FHddijIghVJe9GFUmGA1OOrwnN5kDU51XwkZhmsX1hy-Qa8vYn5I7cJf8mCCXCWFjzCalhmT7ytMiguE5nd91uy8E7Pg4-GT6Y6nhkuO4abpnnqXIe5R4zrgrOdGJjSXEj3bjB7yhWsKiCPcWCDXIUdJiS8e8fNhzDMmXmlp0f)

This can be made more readable by using `itertools.pairwise` to iterate rows with their respective previous rows:

```
from itertools import pairwise

for prev, lst in pairwise(list_of_lists):
    for pos, value in enumerate(lst):
        if value is False:
            lst[pos] = prev[pos]
```

Demo: [here](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=pZLPigIxDMbBY1_BS26jMB529SCCV19iGKS7tGyhMylNZsRn8eJFH2qfZtv55yoyIOaShu_7JZDmdHVH_sHyfL5UrBfr38lUeyzAOW9KBlM49NxVolEMK8-IlgZRGn8wpISwhniPeh8zwRYyASGy5BvtR5LCTlpSYylP74GYP0fBR6LTYrmUz8kx5Osl5B-5St4mRC40enBe1SlYCrsvh9XO7jY73zTNGzdSCrW0lYp2VVaF8pKDn7hzxTC691A77CbFCOYsNMrDj8XpzVu0X_4wuL2R7lT6k_kD)

Comment: that is a terrific way of approaching it, I did not think to use itertools.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an example, where *a* is the list.

```py
for i in range(1, len(a)):
    r = a[i - 1]
    for j in range(len(r)):
        if v := r[j]: a[i][j] = v
```

Output

```
[['col1', False, False, False, False, False],
 ['col1', 'col2', False, False, False, False],
 ['col1', 'col2', 'col3a', False, False, False],
 ['col1', 'col2', 'col3a', False, False, False],
 ['col1', 'col2', 'col3a', 'col4', False, False],
 ['col1', 'col2', 'col3a', 'col4', False, False]]
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output.